# How can I convert hexadecimal color code values to exact shade in php?

Tags: php

[image]

The #codes values that are show in option tag is actually the color code values.I need to show exact color shade besides this value so that any person can understand what color is he picking.How can I do that in php and javascript? Please help me

Comment: Can you share code that you've already written?

Comment: nothing till now.. bit confused

Comment: Do you know the colour code values before hand?

Comment: yes... I have a color management module. From there I am adding them

Comment: You only want the picked color code or a box with color for every option?

Comment: One more question.  Are you using jquery?

Comment: no these values are coming from database

Comment: No I mean on the front-end.  Do you use the jquery library or pure JS?

Comment: i am using jquery library and i want box with color for every option

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how you can set the colour when the user picks a colour.  This should be fairly easy to understand.  Whenever the user changes the select option, I get the value and set the background of the #color-picked element.  This is done using pure JS rather than jQuery.

```
<?php
$colors = ['#ff0000','#00ff00','#0000ff'];
?>
<select onchange="colorChange()" id = "color-picker">
    <?php
    foreach ($colors as $color) {
        echo "<option value='$color'>$color</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<div id="color-picked">

</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #color-picker {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
    }

    #color-picked {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function colorChange() {
        colorPicker = document.getElementById('color-picker');
        colorPicked = document.getElementById('color-picked');
        colorPicked.style.background = colorPicker.value
        console.log(colorPicker.value)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes it worked perfectly.. can you help me with multi select?If a person wants to choose multiple colors ..